# Android phone need to place against the NFC card to discover NFC Tags

Tags: android, nfc

I'm developing the Android Phone become the NFC reader that can be read the smartcard (Visa/ Master). Everything go well but one thing I realized that can not discovered the NFC Tags from the cards in static mode (place the phone near by the card before **enableNFCReaderMode**). But after **enableNFCReaderMode**, I place the phone or the card near by each other, the NFC Tags can be discovered.

Anyone can explain to me why this happening? I expected the card can be read by the phone in the way place them nearby before starting.

Comment: Oh I know that is a limitation from Android platform, we need to move either the Phone or the Card if we want the NFC reader from the Phone to detect the NFC card. Thanks